# SIGSEGV, after mmapping area

Tags: c, linux, memory, mmap

I am trying to revive process from core dump after SIGQUIT.
I really want that piece of virtual memory, yet I get SIGSEGV when I try to map it.

EDIT: This area isn't free: 0xf75d2000 - 0xf7774000, but still i want to have it.
[image]

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <elf.h>
#include <sys/procfs.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <asm/ldt.h>
#include  <signal.h>
bool flag = false;
int argc2;
char ** argv2;
int main2(){
    FILE * file = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r");
    if (file) {
        char c;
        while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
        fclose(file);
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    void* res = mmap((void*)(0xf75d2000), 0x001a5000, PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_FIXED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    argc2 = argc;
    argv2 = argv;
    ucontext_t cont;
    getcontext (&cont);
    if(!flag){
      void* a = mmap((void*)0x34B000, 81920, PROT_EXEC | PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_FIXED, -1, 0);
      if(a == MAP_FAILED){
        printf("mmapfail");
        return 1;
      }
      cont.uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_ESP] = 0x355000;
      flag = true;
      setcontext(&cont);
    } else{
      exit(main2());
    }
}
```

I'm compiling it with:

```
gcc -static -Wl,-Ttext=0x4A9480,--build-idone,-Tdata=0x639480,--section-start=.plt=0x3B9480,--section-start=.rel.plt=0x3AF480,--section-start=.note.ABI-tag=0x39B480 main.c -o main -m32
```

Answer (score 1):

The address you are trying to map (`0xf75d2000`) is above the userspace/kernel split in virtual memory. If your kernel is configured with `CONFIG_VMSPLIT_3G`, you can't map arbitrary addresses above `0xc0000000`.

The existing mappings were setup in kernel to expose the vDSO space (to assist with system calls).

Comment: that would be true if i had pure x86, but i am running it on x64, nice try though

Comment: If you compiling with -m32, won't that create a 32bit executable with a 32bit virtual address space?

Comment: it's just x86 emulated in x64 i can mmap it all

Comment: do you have any idea how can i move that vdso and vvar parts away from there?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you get a SEGV. You map things with `MAP_FIXED` into some address that doesn't belong to you, then you pull the stack from under your feet. You cannot do this.

The address space is not yours to mess around in. `MAP_FIXED` is only safe for overwriting earlier mappings. You can possibly play around in it in a single experiment where you'll throw away the program afterwards, but any other use is just not going to work.

Right now your call to `setcontext` will crash because it doesn't know where to return. Do you even know how function calls and the stack interact? Your call to setcontext saves the return address on the stack, then setcontext changes the stack pointer then it tries to return and dies because it reads 0 as the return address (or setcontext maybe saves the old stack pointer in some other register and will restore it from that register before it returns and what crashes is your other mmap that overwrites the real stack). Please don't do this. Your only chance to reliably change stacks without being the operating system is to set up a signal handler with `sigaltstack`, catch that signal and never return from the signal handler.

But since you're mapping the memory for your new stack with MAP_FIXED into some random address you'll probably overwrite some other important data structure and it still won't work.

Comment: This is plainly wrong. The program doesn't crash, you can e.g. replace mmap with printf and it will work. You can print the esp in the function and you'll see that it changes the stack pointer indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The address space needs to be claimed before other areas are claimed, therefore it needs to be claimed in the executable's metadata.

Create an section in assembly language, then specify it's address in a command line argument to the linker.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern char mem[];

asm (R"(
  .section fixed, "aw", @nobits
  .global mem
mem:
  .zero 0x20000000
)");

int main() {
  printf("mem = %p\n", mem);
}
```

Compile and link with:

```
gcc -O2 -Wl,--section-start=fixed=0x40000000 -fno-pie -no-pie test.c
```

Unfortunately using GCC's `__attribute__((Section("fixed")))` on a variable definition GCC results in a executable bloated with zeros.